# Three button mouse on X

Tags: linux, mouse, xorg

I have a three button mouse, but the middle button is not doing anything. Left & right together are mapping to what the middle mouse button should be doing.

How can I setup X to use a three button mouse?

I'm using Ubuntu Server, installed X from apt-get. Also, I'm using fluxbox for the window manager.

I just need to get the button working, the wheel is currently working properly.

Comment: The wheel or an actual middle button? also what Linux distribution are you using? it may make things a bit easier.

Comment: Edited my question with some more details

Comment: By 'button' do you mean pressing on the wheel so it clicks, or another separate button?

Comment: I mean pressing the wheel down.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `xev` in a terminal and click the affected button in the test window that pops up. It should register an event.

Also, test the mouse on another machine. Eliminate variables.

Comment: it doesn't give an event, but it does for left and right, and together it sends mouse button two. The mouse works, I've been using it for a long time, including on that computer in a previous install, the mouse works perfectly. I'm fairly confident that X is just not configured to use a three button mouse (though I'm not sure why the scroll wheel would work in that case).

Comment: Looks like it's not configured for 3-button mice. Try mucking with your xorg.config file, if one even exists in Ubuntu these days.

Answer (score 0):

It may be time to look in you `xorg.conf` file. (Use `locate xorg.conf` to find it) You'll need to be root to edit it (i.e. use `sudo`).

Use `man xorg.conf` for a fairly detailed description of the contents. You're looking for the "InputDevice" section to start. On my Debian box the mouse details are in the `mouse (4)` manpage.